# Conversion from HIDL type to AIDL

Tags: android, android-ndk, aidl, hidl

I have an android HIDL hal project which needs to be ported to AIDL type. While porting the code from HIDL, I could not find a corresponding API for below function,

`::android::hardware::interfacesEqual(...)` - This is part of HIDL.

Can anyone suggest which function should be used instead of the above? I am using ndk as AIDL backend.